# Программа иерархии классов на C++

Tags: c++

Всем привет, помогите исправить программу на C++. Уже несколько раз изменял код, каждый раз получается неправильно. Картинку иерархии класса прикрепил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот текст программы:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

class B{
 int a;
public:
 B() { };
 B(int x) { a=x; }
 void show_B() { cout <<"B=   "<< a << "\n"; }
};

class D1: public B, protected D4 {
 int b;
public:
 D1(int x, int y) : B(y) { b=x;};
 void show_D1() { cout <<"D1=  "<< b << "\n"; show_B(); show_D4}
};

class D2: protected B, public D3{
 int c;
public:
 D2(int x, int y) : B(y) { c=x;};
 void show_D2() { cout <<"D2=  "<< c << "\n"; show_B(); show_D3}
};

class D3: public D2, private D4 {
 int d;
public:
 D3(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j) : D1(y,z), D2(i,j) { d=x;}
 void show_D3() { cout << "D3=  "<<d << "\n"; show_D2(); show_D4();}
};

class D4: protected D1, private D3 {
 int e;
public:
 D4(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j) : D1(y,z), D2(i,j) { e=x;}
 void show_D4() { cout <<"D4=  "<< e << "\n"; show_D1(); show_D3();}
};

main() {
clrscr();
D3 temp(100,200,300,400,500);
D4 temp1(1,2,3,4,5);
cout << "D3 temp(100,200,300,400,500);\n";
cout << "D4 temp1(1,2,3,4,5);\n";
cout<< "\nСледуя иерархии класса D3: \n";
temp.show_D3();
cout<< "\nСледуя иерархии класса D4\n";
temp1.show_D4();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: какая ошибка-то?

Comment: Начните с того, что уберите `.h` в `#include <iostream.h>` и допишите `using std::cout;`. И внимательно реализуйте классы. Они идут сверху вниз, так что D1 наследует B, а вы пытаетесь его еще и от D4 наследовать. Так вы хотите какое-то циклическое наследование построить - но без машины времени вряд ли получится "дедушка родил папу, пара родил меня, а я уехал прошлое и родил дедушку..." :)

Comment: Прежде чем писать код, разберитесь, что такое наследование. А то вы D2 наследуете от D3, а потом  D3 наследуете от D2.... Это в корне неверно.